# Замена последующих N строк в столбце на 0 после нахождения значения по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация, numpy

Как сделать так, чтобы в последнем столбце после самой первой двойки, последующие N строк были заменены на 0? Скажем, 20 строк после первой найденной 2, если затем (после 20 нулей) будет еще 2, то еще последующие 20 строк = 0.

Пример данных (речь об 3-ем столбце конечно же):

```
11:55   1.10645224  0
11:56   1.10645224  0
11:57   1.10645224  1
11:58   1.10645224  1
11:59   1.10645224  1
12:00   1.10645224  1
12:01   1.10645224  2
12:02   1.10645224  1
12:03   1.10645224  1
12:04   1.10645224  1
12:05   1.10645224  1
12:06   1.10645224  1
12:07   1.10645224  1
12:08   1.10645224  2
12:09   1.10645224  1
12:10   1.10645224  1
12:11   1.10645224  2
12:12   1.10645224  1
12:13   1.10645224  1
12:14   1.10645224  1
12:15   1.10645224  1
12:16   1.10645224  1
```

Пример [данных на dropmefiles](https://dropmefiles.com/pLnGP).

Итог N = 10:

```
11:55   1.10645224  0
11:56   1.10645224  0
11:57   1.10645224  1
11:58   1.10645224  1
11:59   1.10645224  1
12:00   1.10645224  1
12:01   1.10645224  2
12:02   1.10645224  0
12:03   1.10645224  0
12:04   1.10645224  0
12:05   1.10645224  0
12:06   1.10645224  0
12:07   1.10645224  0
12:08   1.10645224  0
12:09   1.10645224  0
12:10   1.10645224  0
12:11   1.10645224  0
12:12   1.10645224  1
12:13   1.10645224  1
12:14   1.10645224  1
12:15   1.10645224  1
12:16   1.10645224  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Алгоритм**:

1. находим индексы всех интересующих нас элементов
2. устанавливаем правую границу интервала - первый индекс + N
3. обнуляем N элементов между первым найденным индексом и правой границей
4. цикл по найденным индексам, начиная со второго

   1. если текущий индекс <= правой границе (пред. индекс + N), то пропускаем его
   2. сдвигаем правую границу - текущий индекс + N
   3. обнуляем элементы между тек. индекс + 1 и правой границей

**NOTE:** цикл будет работать достаточно быстро, т.к. число итераций равно количеству искомых элементов (`2` в вашем случае)

---

Код:

```
def f(col, N=10, search_for=2, fill_value=0):
    s = col.reset_index(drop=True)
    idx_list = s.loc[s==search_for].index
    idx = idx_list[0]
    s.loc[idx+1: idx+N] = fill_value
    right_boundary = idx + N
    for ii in idx_list[1:]:
        # print(ii, ii+1, right_boundary)
        if ii <= right_boundary:
            continue
        right_boundary = ii + N
        s.loc[ii+1: right_boundary] = fill_value
    return pd.Series(s.to_numpy(), index=col.index)
```

---

```
In [288]: d = pd.read_csv(r"C:\download\data_1.csv", index_col=0)

In [289]: idx = d.query("Threshold == 2").index

In [290]: idx
Out[290]: Int64Index([1457, 1464, 1467, 1995], dtype='int64')

In [291]: d["new"] = f(d["Threshold"], 10)
```

---

```
In [294]: d.loc[1457:1457+12]
Out[294]:
            Date   Time        72  Threshold  new
1457  2015.07.06  12:01  1.106452          2    2
1458  2015.07.06  12:02  1.106452          1    0
1459  2015.07.06  12:03  1.106452          1    0
1460  2015.07.06  12:04  1.106452          1    0
1461  2015.07.06  12:05  1.106452          1    0
1462  2015.07.06  12:06  1.106452          1    0
1463  2015.07.06  12:07  1.106452          1    0
1464  2015.07.06  12:08  1.106452          2    0
1465  2015.07.06  12:09  1.106452          1    0
1466  2015.07.06  12:10  1.106452          1    0
1467  2015.07.06  12:11  1.106452          2    0
1468  2015.07.06  12:12  1.106452          1    1
1469  2015.07.06  12:13  1.106452          1    1
```

Comment: @Vlad, ничего элегантного на ум не приходит из-за перекрывающихся интервалов